# how can I make the material on the surface different color than the sprinkles on this cube?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, color

**EDIT**
I have played around with colors in Blender and I have yet a problem:
how can I make the background in different color than the sprinkles
on the cube ? Say, I want to make the background in red and sprinkles
in random green as they presently are. What shall I touch ? Please see the first snippet. I've almost succeeded with shader but the background is still green.

[image]

I have a wonder what to touch so that the cube in the snippet below becomes blue.
I'm new to blender.

[image]

Comment: Hello, You've created a new texture that is blue but now you need to assign the texture to the object, please show the Shader Editor to see if you've correctly plugged the nodes

Comment: @moonboots Could you please have a look at my **EDIT** ?

Comment: @moonboots Or it would even suffice, if different color of the background is not possible, that it would appear as in the picture in the answer below: like a mesh grid instead of my colorful background. How can I achieve this but maintaining the full random green color of the cube ?

Comment: Could you please give me a .blend file ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, is Christopher's answer not accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color, you must use the Material Properties tab:

[image: Color]

To answer your edit, if you want the cube to have a different color than the sprinkles, you have to use different materials for the Cube and Particle Instance objects, respectively.

**CUBE MATERIAL**

[image: Cube1]

**PARTICLE MATERIAL** (On sphere and cone)

[image: Cube2]

EDIT - Here is a file with the Cube, as requested:

[image]

Comment: Can you please have a look at my **EDIT** ?

Comment: Could you please give me a `.blend` file of the red cube ?

Comment: I added a file, if you want it.